# Using logic app , What is best of way of triggering email when data is inserted or updated in Azure SQL table?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

The new entry is created in the SQL azure table for any new request from the user. Then another user can modify that entry either by approving or rejecting the request.

Each time data is inserted or modified in table i want to generate an email using logic app connector.

I have used SQL server connectors to do this but sometimes email is triggered multiple times as only 1 logic app is sending an email for requester and approval flow.
[image]

> Is there any way to archive this using recurrence trigger?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to archive this using recurrence trigger?

Yes, if you own the database, you can store one of two widely used patterns:

1. Add a flag to the table indicating a notification status.  Then call a stored procedure that retrieves the pending rows and sets the flag to 'sent' or whatever is appropriate.
2. Use a Trigger on the table to add update events in a separate table, then on the Recurrence, call a Stored Procedure that returns the condensed list.

It will be much easier to filter/merge row updates in a SP than in the Logic App.

Comment: you can store the update events in a separate table. How to do this?